# How to dynamically update autohotkey GUI elements

Tags: autohotkey

I've created a GUI using AHK. I am storing the Id and description as key-value pairs. I want to update the Desc when the user enters the ID with the corresponding desc stored in the associative array. How can I dynamically updated the GUI?

```
^h::

oKeys := []
oValues := []
oArray := {}


if (WinExist("ahk_id " hwndgui)) {
    Gui, Destroy
    return
}

gui, add, text,, Type:
Gui, Add, DropDownList,vType, TSO|PAX|DVI 
gui, add, text,, ID:
Gui, Add, Edit, vId
gui, add, text,, Partial|Complete:
Gui, Add, DropDownList,vPartial, Partial||Complete
gui, add, text,, Left-Behind:
Gui, Add, DropDownList,vLeft, False||True
gui, add, text,, XFR-Type:
Gui, Add, DropDownList,vXFR, Standard||Contact|Theft
gui, add, text,, DESC:
Gui, Add, Edit, vDesc , oArray[(TypeId)]
Gui, Add, Button, Default gOK, OK

Gui, Show, Hide

Gui, +LastFound
hwndgui:=WinExist()
OK:
Gui, Submit

oKeys.Push((TypeId))
oValues.Push((Desc))
Loop, % oKeys.Length()
oArray[oKeys[A_Index]] := oValues[A_Index]
    

if WinExist("labelImg")
    WinActivate  ; Uses the last found window.
    Send, ^a
    Send, %Type%_%Id%_%Partial%_%Desc%
    for vKey, vValue in oArray
    vOutput .= vKey " " vValue "`r`n"
    MsgBox, % vOutput
    
Gui, Show
return
```

Comment: Could you post a more minimal example or a more detailed explanation of what is supposed to happen with this code? I really can't make sense what you're trying to do, but the question itself sounds like it has a very simple solution, one that I for sure will know.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I basically want to update the value of an EditBox based on the values entered by the user in a particular EditBox. For example, If the user enters details in Type and ID, It should check the associated array for an existing key-value pair of format TypeID = Desc. If it is there we need to update the default value of desc with that value

Comment: It's still hard to understand. At least I definitely can't tell what the stuff under the `if WinExist` at the bottom is. But you're at least going to want to use [GuiControl](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GuiControl.htm#Blank) to edit your controls (e.g. `GuiControl, , Desc, hello`)

Comment: I just need an example of how to detect focus lost on an edit text box and update another edit box value with it. I have tried using GuiControl but it doesn't seem to work as needed.